# How to Reference the "SpaceBar" Key in C# (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity, how do I reference the SpaceBar Key in order to apply force to an object when Space Bar is pressed?

```
void Update()
{
    rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardforce * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetKey("a"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, -500 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("s"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, 500 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("d"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(-500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("vbKeySpace"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(0, 300 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test just using `Input.GetKey(" ")`?

Comment: I see that you are mapping the keys AWSD, you should look into using Input.GetAxis (). Makes your code simpler and you don't have to use negative forces.

Answer (score 9):

You could try the following:

```
Input.GetKey("space");
```

Or, using the KeyCode enumeration:

```
Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space);
```

See the docs on this enumeration [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html).

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3):

`Input.GetKey` operates on the string-names of the [Conventional Game Input](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html#Keys) key list.

> Special keys: “backspace”, “tab”, “return”, “escape”, “space”, “delete”, “enter”, “insert”, “home”, “end”, “page up”, “page down”

However, I recommend looking into `Input.GetButton` instead.  This allows the player to rebind the keys to something more suitable for them, rather than being forced to use WASD and Space.

So you would instead use `Input.GetButton("Jump")` and define in Edit -> Project Settings -> Input that "Jump" is mapped to the positive key "space" (Unity will auto-supply some default keys, and Jump:Space is one).

Additionally you can switch your `Input.GetKey("a")`/`Input.GetKey("d")` with [`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html).